# How to sum all values in column?

Tags: javascript, typescript, exceljs

I'm using `exceljs` and i must sum all values from my column, how can i do this?

at issue on github, i found one solution, but not work for me:

```
workSheet.getCell(`B${endRow}`).value = { formula: `SUM(B4:B${endRow-1})` };
```

because vscode throw me: `Type '{ formula: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CellValue'. Type '{ formula: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'CellSharedFormulaValue': sharedFormula, date1904`

can somebody tell me how to sum each values from column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, try to modify your code like this:

```
workSheet.getCell(`B${endRow}`).value = { formula: `SUM(B4:B${endRow-1})`, date1904: false };
```

Comment: Thanks, adding `date1904: false` stopped the error.

Comment: Why is this happening? I certainly beleive this is not the intended behaviour

Comment: @JuanPabloC I think this is a bug (https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/1329). Looks like is still open since 2020... Sorry to not be more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit late im adding this for anyone who came across the same issue.

1. point number one your array object values must be of type number not string.
   I created a method to do that for me which is convertStringToNumber(data);

Example data

```
     [{ItemPrice: 69.99, name: "Kellogs Cornflakes", brand: "Kellogs", Quantity_Purchased: 2, QaunititySaleValue: 139.98}, {ItemPrice: 19.99, name: "Castle Lite", brand: "Castle", Quantity_Purchased: 2, QaunititySaleValue: 39.98}]
```

Code

```
async createExcel(data, fileName) {

let xlsData = this.convertStringToNumber(data);
const fs = require('fs')

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(fileName);

worksheet.columns = [
  { header: 'name', key: 'name', width: 10 },
  { header: 'brand', key: 'brand', width: 32 },
  { header: 'Quantity_Purchased', key: 'Quantity_Purchased', width: 15, },
  { header: 'ItemPrice', key: 'ItemPrice', width: 15, },
  { header: 'QaunititySaleValue', key: 'QaunititySaleValue', width: 15, }
];

worksheet.addRows(xlsData);

const endRow = worksheet.lastRow._number + 1;

worksheet.getCell(`C${endRow}`).value = { formula: `SUM(C2:C${endRow - 1})` };
worksheet.getCell(`D${endRow}`).value = { formula: `SUM(D2:D${endRow - 1})` };
worksheet.getCell(`E${endRow}`).value = { formula: `SUM(E2:E${endRow - 1})` };
// save under export.xlsx
let buffResult = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();

fs.writeFileSync(fileName + ".xlsx", buffResult); }

 convertStringToNumber(objects) {
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
   var obj = objects[i];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj[prop])) {
      obj[prop] = +obj[prop];
    }
  }
}
return objects; }
```

Output
[image]